# Handle multiple parameters in array_map call back

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I have the following code:

```
$a=array(15,12,13,25,27,36,18);
$b=array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1);//is it possible to pass only one value=1, instead of array containing seven 1's
// expectation: $b = array(1); or $b= 1; 
//instead of $b=array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1);

function array_add($p,$q){
   return($p+$q);
}
$c=array_map("array_add",$a,$b);
```

I want something like:

```
$a=array(15,12,13,25,27,36,18);
$b=array(1);

function array_add($p,$q){
   return($p+$q);
}
$c=array_map("array_add",$a,$b);
```

Any better solution thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please provide an example With expected behaviour.

Comment: $a=array(15,12,13,25,27,36,18);
$b=array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1); // I want to use one value for all indexes instead of array i.e. $b = 1; 

function array_add($p,$q){
   return($p+$q);
}
$c=array_map("array_add",$a,$b);

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map` as this, and pass the $param2 with `use()`

```
array_map(function($v) use($param2){
    //do something
}, $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

From Your example, it would be:

```
function array_add( &$item, $key, $toAdd) { 
   $item+=$toAdd;
}
array_walk($a, 'array_add', 1);
```

I would also recommend that you have a look at the answer provided using closure(`use`)